# three dropdownlist with auto postback

Tags: c#, combobox, webforms

I have three `dropdownlist` with `autopostback = true`. first chose country and appear cities in second `dropdownlist` then select city from second `dropdownllist` and appear regions in third drop downlist. but problem is that when i select third value in first `dropdownlist`(for example USA) and then select one of the values in second dropdownlist (for example `Los angles`) the page is refreshed and usa selected and then first value in second `dropdownlist` is selected( I can't select another value because with page refresh the first value is selecting again.

Comment: Are you re-populating all of your drop-downs on post-back? Are you able to provide the C# code?

Comment: @Richard there is no code because it is ADO.net

Answer (score 0):

You need to either set a default value (e.g "Please Select...")

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Please Select..." Value="" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

---

Or on your `SelectedIndexChanged` event for the 1st dropdown, bind the 2nd dropdown, and then immediately bind the 3rd dropdown based on the 2nd's selected value.

In theory:

```
public void ddl1_selectedindexchanged(){
   BindDdl2();
   BindDdl3();
}

public void ddl2_selectedindexchanged(){
   BindDdl3();
}

private void BindDdl2(){
   int selectedvalue = ddl1.SelectedValue;
   //bind ddl2
}

private void BindDdl3(){
   int selectedvalue = ddl2.SelectedValue;
   //bind ddl3
}
```

Comment: @Mahdi_Nine Perhaps To clarify the issue you are having is that when the second dropdown is bound, its not possible to bind the 3rd dropdown with the 1st option in the second dropdown because its already selected?

Comment: when i select USA in first dropdown list and then select Los Angles in second drop dropdown list the page is refreshed and automaticly the first item in second dropdown list is selected so i can't select any element because after page refresh the first element in second dropdown list is selected automaticly.do you want show with code?